# Load an external stylesheet in QT from another external stylesheet

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

I'm new to QT and I'm trying to see if it's possible to load an external stylesheet from a global stylesheet just like in web dev, something like using the syntax "link rel="stylesheet".

Right now we have a global CSS sheet that is being called via C++ code with all the global elements and specific widget modifications, it has 2k lines of code and it's becoming unmanageable. I know I can keep the global file and start adding resource stylesheets or pure code put directly into QT Creator Style Sheet editor for each widget. However, the head of development really wants to separate that my code from his team, so avoid any changes in QT UI file as much as possible, so if something breaks he will know when it was me or him.

Is this possible? can I call a stylesheet from a stylesheet? I couldn't find this syntax in the QT guide.

Comment: No, you can't. Take a look at QtQuick + QML. It has better abstraction of code from GUI. Qt stylesheets doesn't support full costomization.